# C# how to wait for an sql query to finish?

Tags: c#

I do switch the view between two panels (i play with the visibility), on each switch there is an SQL query, but it takes one to two seconds, and thus the switch between the panels gets like cut, is there a way to handle the cut like waiting for the query to finish before switching the view ?

**EDIT** : how to wait for an sql query to finish before doing any other action?

Comment: Its really not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: learn how to formulate a question

Comment: Beyond yes lots, there's no way to answer this question. What do you want to happen?

Comment: You could perform long running job outside of UI thread. Use `Thread`, `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` for this. Once job is completed it can `Invoke` method, which will change panel visibility or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep a responsive UI, you could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) to do the query.